# How to create class instance inside that class method?

Tags: python, class, instance

I want to create class instance inside itself. I tried to it by this way:

```
class matrix:
    (...)
    def det(self):
        (...)
        m = self(sz-1, sz-1)
        (...)
    (...)
```

but I got error:

> ```
> m = self(sz-1, sz-1)
> ```
>
> AttributeError: matrix instance has no `__call__` method

So, I tried to do it by this way:

```
class matrix:
    (...)
    def det(self):
        (...)
        m = matrix(sz-1, sz-1)
        (...)
    (...)
```

and I got another error:

> ```
> m = matrix(sz-1, sz-1)
> ```
>
> NameError: global name 'matrix' is not defined

Of course matrix is not global class. I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: The last example works for me.

Comment: As you have it right now, 'm' would be a local variable, not an instance variable, so it will disappear when the det() method returns. This might be appropriate for what you're doing, but when you say you want a "class instance inside itself" it sounds like you might want m to be an instance variable, in which case you need to refer to it as "self.m"

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: The last example works in my Python 2.6.4.  I would not expect anything else…

Comment: the last example could work if matrix was global class, but it isn't. Maybe in python 2.6 it works, I don't know, I'm using 2.5.4.

'm' is local variable because I don't need it outside det() method - I calculate matrix determinant in recursion way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
m = self.__class__(sz-1, sz-1)
```

or

```
m = type(self)(sz-1, sz-1)
```

Comment: Okay, but type(self) is matrix, isn't it? So why doesn't pablo's second example work? Is it just a fact of life that you can't refer to a class from within itself in Python?

Comment: I'm deleting my hack of an answer in favor of this gem.

Comment: type(self)() doesn't work for me, but self.__class__() works properly and it's everything I needed. Thanks ;)

Comment: @MatrixFrog: For "old-style" classes (python2 classes that don't inherit from object), `type(self)` is always just `<type 'instance'>`. The metaclass / new style classes was to enable users to make "real" types.